# Get a message sent to only one guild when my bot is added to a server

Tags: discord.py

I am new to coding so sorry if this is easy to do. But what I am wanting to have my bot do is send a message to my private guild when it is added or removed from another guild. Also if it could say the name of said guild that would help as well.

Comment: There is an event called `on_guild_join` and `on_guild_remove`. Use these events to track the server. For further help, please provide use with some code that you have done. Without any research, you won't get that far here.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
  chn = client.get_channel(YOUR_PRIVATE_GUILD_CHANNEL_ID)
  embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Bot Invited",description=f"""
  **User Name:** {bot_entry[0].user.name}
  **User ID:** {bot_entry[0].user.id}
  **Server Name:** {guild.name}
  **Server ID:** {guild.id}
  **Members Count:** {len(guild.members)}
  """, colour=0x2dc6f9)
  embed.set_footer(icon_url=guild.icon_url, text=guild.name)
  embed.set_author(name=f"{bot_entry[0].user.name}#{bot_entry[0].user.discriminator}", icon_url=bot_entry[0].user.avatar_url)
  embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
  server_invite = await guild.text_channels[0].create_invite(max_age = 0, max_uses = 0)
  await chn.send(f"{server_invite}", embed=embed)
```

Comment: The same can be done using the `on_guild_remove` event. It works technically the same.

Comment: When I put it in I get the error invalid syntax on the line with the guild id. I placed my guild id and channel id in the right spots. Where is the error coming from

Comment: What error to be exact?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
   await client.get_channel(idchannel).send(f"{client.name} has joined")
```

Comment: Does not seem so work

Comment: I was mainly asking is it the join event you want or something that displays the whole guild member stuff on join.